# How to create an Run Length decoder in python?

Tags: python, list, decoder, run-length-encoding

I need the decoder to take input like

```
[3, 15, 6, 4]
```

and output

```
[15, 15, 15, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

I already have an encoder that works perfectly, but I am unsure how I would go about reversing the process.

Comment: "latest version" isn't very useful tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
lst = [3, 15, 6, 4]

output = [x for n, x in zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]) for _ in range(n)]
print(output) # [15, 15, 15, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to use a nested `list` comprehension (i.e. equivalent to two `for` loops), iterating over the even indices of the list `L`:

```py
>>> L = [3, 15, 6, 4]
>>> [e for i in range(0, len(L), 2) for e in L[i] * [L[i + 1]]]
[15, 15, 15, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

---

A way of achieving the same, using a single `for` loop and `list.extend`:

```py
>>> L = [3, 15, 6, 4]
>>> result = []
>>> for i in range(0, len(L), 2):
...   result.extend(L[i] * [L[i + 1]])
...
>>> result
[15, 15, 15, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. One is list multiplication and summation:

```
sum((lst[n] * lst[n + 1:n + 2] for n in range(0, len(lst), 2)), start=[])
```

You can also use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) instead of `sum`:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(lst[n] * lst[n + 1:n + 2] for n in range(0, len(lst), 2)))
```

You can also use [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to evaluate the expansion even more lazily:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(lst[n + 1], lst[n]) for n in range(0, len(lst), 2)))
```

If you're willing to use numpy, you can do

```
np.repeat(lst[1::2], lst[::2])
```

Comment: Small variation: `list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, lst[1::2], lst[::2])))`

Answer (score 0):

@j1-lee's answer works but creates temporary lists that may be an issue if space efficiency is a concern.

You can create an iterator over the input list instead to iterate through the list in a space-efficient manner:

```
lst = [3, 15, 6, 4]
seq = iter(lst)
print([i for n, i in zip(seq, seq) for _ in range(n)])
```

This outputs:

```
[15, 15, 15, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```